# split and trim puzzle in GAS - a bug in debugger?

Tags: google-apps-script

I was debugging my GAS script where I want to remove white space I realized that I need to remove all whitespaces not just from both ends. Then I found something strange around trim(), split(). So I created this simple function.

When you run it in debugger then the value of textTMP you see in log and in debugger is different. See the [image].

```
function splitTest(){

  var text = " part1   part2";

  var textTMP = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'');
  var tmpSpace3 = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/gm,'').split(" ");
  var tmpSpace4 = textTMP.split(" ");

  var ttt = text.trim();
  var tmpSpace = ttt.split(" ");

  var tmpSpace2 = text.trim().split(" ");

  var regex = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\s+(?=\s)/g, "");;
  var tmpSpace5 = regex.split(" ");

  console.log("text:'"+text+"'");
  console.log("textTMP:'"+textTMP+"'"); 
  console.log("regex:'"+regex+"'");

  console.log(textTMP.split(" "));
  console.log(tmpSpace);    
  console.log(tmpSpace2);  
  console.log(tmpSpace3);  
  console.log(tmpSpace4); 
  console.log(tmpSpace5);     
  console.log("fiished");
}
```

**UPDATE**
the code does not have any meaning. I was just testing different ways how to get rid of whitespaces in a string and how to replicate the issue I was having in GAS debbuger.

Comment: Could you comment your code to better illustrate what you mean?

Comment: the code does not have any meaning. I was just testing different ways how to get rid of whitespaces in a string and how to replicate the issue I was having in GAS debbuger.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the bug or the current specification, when I had been testing the debug using new IDE, I had also the same situation that the multiple spaces are displayed as one space. I cannot still find this at the issue tracker. For example, how about reporting this to the issue tracker?

Comment: I created a bug report in their Tracker

Comment: I really dont understand people voting to close without leaving any comment. This issue was recoginised as a bug by Google. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180324076

Answer (score 1):

As @Radek points out this is an issue . Feel free to add a "star" to the issue to give it more visibility here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/180324076